# NSTextField and NSComboBox are drawn differently in Lion

Tags: cocoa, macos, user-interface, osx-lion, appkit

I've got a data form I developed under Snow Leopard, that has `NSTextField` boxes alongside `NSComboBox` fields, and this looked fine under Snow Leopard, but now in Lion, they're drawn slightly differently. I also have some `NSComboBox` fields with a bordered button, and some with an unordered button, and these don't match, either (though the bordered button `NSComboBox` looks close to the `NSTextField`, though it's not a match, either.

How can I get everything to harmoniously match? I'd be happy to get an `NSTextField` to autocomplete like a combo box, since I hide the button anyway.

Non-Bordered `NSComboBox` left, `NSTextField` right (different top edge):

[image: Non-Bordered Combo vs. Text Field]

Bordered `NSComboBox left,`NSTextField` right (different heights):

[image: Bordered Combo vs. Text Field]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up replacing my non-bordered combo boxes (for which I had been hiding the buttons) with `NSTextField` controls, using the method here: [NSTextField AutoCompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525250/nstextfield-autocompletion-delegate-method-not-called/5525540#5525540).

I modified it slightly:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj {
    if (!isAutoCompleting) {
        isAutoCompleting = YES;
        [[[obj userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"] complete:nil];
        isAutoCompleting = NO;
    }
}
```

When I want the `NSComboBox` button to be visible, I use the bordered style, which matches closely enough.

Comment: Glad you found my answer useful. Your upvote (I assume) brought it back to my attention, and I just edited it with a bit more info. I found that it was necessary to keep more than just a flag -- my current implementation keeps track of the last string that the user actually typed in and compares it each time with the current `string` of the field editor. Good luck!

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Correct assumption :-)